# Trying to read checkbox values from a JSTL loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting two JSTL loops one loop to display MainMenu and one JSTL to display a submenu. Now I am trying to read checkbox values that are checked on class. I am getting all checkbox values because of the same class in a loop.

My HTML Code looks like:

```
 <div class="card-box table-responsive">
    <c:forEach var="mBean" items="${sessionScope.mainMenuList}" varStatus="status">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8" >
        <span class="accordion">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="sport" value="${mBean.menu_id}">${mBean.menu_name}</span>
        <div class="panel sub-menu">
        <c:forEach var="count" items="${sessionScope.subMenuList.get(status.index)}">
        <div class="row">
        <label id="childrens"><input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="${count.menu_id}">${count.menu_name}</label>
        </div>
        </c:forEach>
        </div>
       </div>
      </c:forEach>
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(".checkbox").click(function() {            
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                $("#childrens input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");

                });
            }else{
                $("#childrens input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                });        
            }
      [![My menu looks like this][1]][1]});
```

Answer (score 0):

ForEach will create multiple checkbox with id "childrens".Since Id should be unique. Use class instead id.